# Image scraping with Android

Tags: java, android, image, zomato-api

Is there a way to scrape multiple images from a website, and display it through our app?

I want to display the images from, let's say, this website https://www.zomato.com/id/jakarta/the-porte-eatery-and-cafe-benda/menu#tabtop

Zomato itself only provides the url of the page.

It provides the menu of the restaurant (multiple images). But there are also thumbnails of other restaurants that I wouldn't want to appear.

Comment: Unless you have a license/permission this is probably against the terms and conditions of the website and Google Play.

Comment: The jpg's url is in the source html...

Answer (score 0):

Zomato API provides only the restaurant's menu page url and we have *no* plans to provide menu images through APIs (or any other means) in the foreseeable future.